# Interval Sampling statistics into Database

Tags: sql, concurrency, statistics, db2

A lot of events of various type is triggered in my application - I want to count them over time to keep track.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I will have multiple servers and threads saving events, so it has to work during concurrency.

I cannot have one row per event, since the number of events is very large, it has to be aggregated somehow.

So, I'm trying to have a table row per event type and "time interval" like

```
COLUMN
------
ID          
EVENTTYPE
COUNT
FIRSTTIMESTAMP
LASTTIMESTAMP
```

I first tried to make a solution where a new row was created by the logger:

```
UDPATE EVENTCOUNTER SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 WHERE LASTTIMESTAMP > CURRENT TIMESTAMP and EVENTTYPE = ?;
```

If num rows updated = 0  then insert a new row with new timestamps.

However, to make this work, I would have to lock the entire table so that there will no be a race condition creating new rows from multiple threads.

i.e.

```
LOCK TABLE EVENTCOUNTER ..
UPDATE .. 
if numRows = 0 then INSERT ..
COMMIT
```

Will this table lock impact performance by a great deal? Is there a better way to solve my problem without table locks?

Using a DB2 database and Java Client - actually Hibernate if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would insert a row for each event and run a script every 24h or so that aggregates the information and puts the aggregated in a separate table. This is the classical way OLAP (analisys services etc.) works.

Since you have many inputs, consider using a less restrictive lock ([here](http://gilroygonsalves.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/db2-95-and-db2-97-locking-tips.html) are the transaction locks for db2). After all, if your aggregated result misses a few entries out of hundreds it's not that bad.

Comment: Thanks. I just though about how to aggregate into the same table, but another table makes more sense. It will complicate things a bit, since I would have to slice it in time frames, but I guess that's doable.

Comment: Having separate tables will make the solution more scalable - in the future you might want to move the aggregated info table to a separate db or even a separate machine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about DB2 but in Oracle there are Insert/Update row or statement level triggers. So, every time user inserts/updates a row trigger fires and does smth. (row level trigger) like update some log or other table as in your case. Not sure if this feature is available in DB2. Just FYI...